# connecting PV cells for different applications

Tags: power-supply, power, solar-cell, solar-energy

PV cells are connected either in series, parallel or a combination of the two. There are some obvious reasons as to why this might be done for example to achieve different currents, voltages and shade resistance.

I have been thinking about how PV panels might be connected for different applications. For example, how would the PV panels on the Mars rover be connected as opposed to a PV panel on the roof of a house and why is it done as such?

I would appreciate some help in understanding this, I have tried looking for some academic/research papers on this but did not find anything which answers the 'how' or 'why' PV cells might be connected in a certain way to achieve a certain outcome.

Comment: You’ve pretty well summed it up yourself. Voltage/current/shade resistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually solar panels are usually connected in [series](https://www.pveducation.org/pvcdrom/modules-and-arrays/mismatch-for-cells-connected-in-series) rather than in [parallel](https://www.pveducation.org/pvcdrom/modules-and-arrays/mismatch-for-cells-connected-in-parallel).

Mismatch is rather complex to calculate on the whole module, and cell were mostly in series to produce a lower current at the same rated power, as the losses are R*I^2, as well as simpler module design and production.

However, new generation of panels have both a mix of series in parallel cells, achieved by cutting the cells in halves, this is called half-cut cells.

One also needs to consider what is the minimum useful voltage, as a cell produce about 0.6V, you need to have at least 5-10V to have some efficient power conversion, charge batteries. On rovers, they most likely use [triple junction solar cells](https://www.intechopen.com/books/optoelectronics-advanced-materials-and-devices/iii-v-multi-junction-solar-cells), which produce a voltage of about 2.7V.

Given that, the most optimal design, would be cells in series, as anyways you need to produce sufficient voltage. Given that anyways you need cells in series (strings), if you want the most robust system, it makes sense to have a controller for each string, as you will have regardless series mismatch, you don't want to add parallels mismatch.

With these considerations, cells in the Rover in mars are most likely connected in series, with each series of cells having it's own controller in order to maximize the power output and lower the risk of impact of any damaged string, if a string where to be shorted, it would take down all the parallel strings, resulting in the loss of the rover. This of course might also depends of the weight of these controllers, cost is probably not even a consideration.

BTW, "big" rovers, like Opportunity and Perseverance uses [nuclear generator](https://www.space.com/mars-rover-perseverance-nuclear-power-source-explained.html) rather than solar cell, as the dust deposition in the panels is a big problems for the rovers over there, coupled with low solar irradiation.

Comment: what do you mean by " mix of series in parallel cells", for example do you mean some cells are connected in series and then each of these series connections is connected in parallel? or the other way around?

Comment: regarding the controller part, why would you need an MPPT controller for each series connection, wouldn't having on MPPT for the whole connection achieve the same result?